# Column being passed in as dataframe after naming arguments in user defined function

Tags: r, statistics

[Newbie here]Stuck at a very weird problem. I have a function to calculate lag, it works fine when the arguments are not named in function, but doesn't when I give them a name.

The following code doesnt work, and prints "data.frame" as class of argument a (when i am passing a column)

```
lagger = function(ind = a,dep = c,lag = b){
  print(class(a))
  print(paste("linear correlation" ,cor(a,c), sep=" "))
  print(paste("log linear correlation:" ,cor(log(a),c), sep=" "))
  print(paste("log log correlation:" ,cor(log(a),log(c)), sep=" "))
  for (i in 1:b){
    del = a
    del <- c(rep(NA,i),a[1:(NROW(a)-i)])
    corr = (cor(del,c,use="complete"))
    corr_log = cor(del,c,use="complete")
    corr_log_log = cor(log(del),log(c),use="complete")
    print(paste(" lag of" ,i , "unit/s :" , round(corr,3) ,"log",round(corr_log,3),"log log",round(corr_log_log,3), sep = "      ") )

  }

}
```

While this code works:

```
lagger = function( a,c,b){
  print(class(a))
  print(paste("linear correlation" ,cor(a,c), sep=" "))
  print(paste("log linear correlation:" ,cor(log(a),c), sep=" "))
  print(paste("log log correlation:" ,cor(log(a),log(c)), sep=" "))
  for (i in 1:b){
    del = a
    del <- c(rep(NA,i),a[1:(NROW(a)-i)])
    corr = (cor(del,c,use="complete"))
    corr_log = cor(del,c,use="complete")
    corr_log_log = cor(log(del),log(c),use="complete")
    print(paste(" lag of" ,i , "unit/s :" , round(corr,3) ,"log",round(corr_log,3),"log log",round(corr_log_log,3), sep = "      ") )

  }

}
```

Why?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your function argument:

```
ind = a
```

means that the value per default of the argument `ind` will be a. 
`ind` is the name of your argument so you must use it in the function instead of `a`.

try this:

```
lagger <- function(ind,dep,lag){
  print(class(ind))
  print(paste("linear correlation" ,cor(ind,dep), sep=" "))
  print(paste("log linear correlation:" ,cor(log(ind),dep), sep=" "))
  print(paste("log log correlation:" ,cor(log(ind),log(dep)), sep=" "))
  for (i in 1:lag){
    del = ind
    del <- c(rep(NA,i),ind[1:(NROW(ind)-i)])
    corr = (cor(del,dep,use="complete"))
    corr_log = cor(del,dep,use="complete")
    corr_log_log = cor(log(del),log(dep),use="complete")
    print(paste(" lag of" ,i , "unit/s :" , round(corr,3) ,"log",round(corr_log,3),"log log",round(corr_log_log,3), sep = "      ") )

  }

}
```

then when you use your function you can use

```
lagger(ind = a, dep =c, lag = b)
```

If a, b and c have been defined.